# What does the 「な」 do in this sentence?

Tags: dialects, keigo, manga, kansai-ben

Here is the sentence said by Kansai speaker. He said this because his companion has annoyed other persons in the same room until they woke up.

そら見い　いよいよおき**な**はったあ。

I think it would work as a filler. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Extra question:** Is the 「はったあ」the past form of 「はる」 or 'to do' in Kansai dialect?

Answer (score 5):

The なはった is the past tense form of なはる, which is the Kansai version of honorific なさる. So [起]{お}きなはった would be like 起きなさった in standard Japanese.

> そら見い　いよいよおきなはったあ
>   ≂ そら見ろ、いよいよ(≂とうとう)起きなさった。(≂ 起きられた / 起きてしまわれた)

---

> Is the 「はったあ」 the past form of 「はる」 or 'to do' in Kansai dialect?

The meaning is the same, just your example uses なはった/なはる. Actually we more commonly say 起きはった here in Kansai, using the (weak honorific) はる.